# How to enlarge/blow up/zoom a certain part of a UIImageView on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, core-animation

I have a magnifying glass as a UIImageView subview of a UIView.  I want to enlarge the part of the UIView that the magnifying glass is on.  I can't figure out how to enlarge a certain part of the view.  I assume it has to be a rectangle and not a circle?  How could I blow it up?  I don't have much CA experience so a shove in the right direction would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to zoom a static image, then you can do this:

Make the magnifyingView (UIView) have a sub-view that's a UIImageView.  The UIImageView has the same image that's being magnified, but much larger.  Have the magnifyingView clip to bounds set.  Then, as the UIView is moved by the user dragging/touching, the subview is moved in relation to that to create a magnify effect.

I'd have to look up how to magnify dynamic content myself.

Answer (score 0):

I am about to do the same thing.  Here is an example of how to capture a view in an image.  You can then zoom in the image in the bubble:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```